# Null reference in NPOI API call when trying to find the font applied to text

Tags: c#, excel, npoi, xssf

I have this sample:

```
IRichTextString richText = cell.RichStringCellValue;
for (int index = 0; index < richText.String.Length; index++)
{
    short fontId = richText.GetFontAtIndex(index);
    ...
}
```

When calling GetFontAtIndex for the first time (index = 0), I'm getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**:

> at NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFRichTextString.ToCTFont(CT_RPrElt pr) at
>   NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFRichTextString.GetFontOfFormattingRun(Int32
>   index)

The file has xlsx extention. For xls this code works fine.

Also tried this, with no luck:

```
for (int i = 0; i < richText.NumFormattingRuns; i++)
{
    int startIdx = richText.GetIndexOfFormattingRun(i);
    int length = richText.GetLengthOfFormattingRun(i);
    IFont font = richText.GetFontOfFormattingRun(i);
    ...
}
```

Where should be the problem? For xlsx files is no way of getting the font for a text?

**Edit:**

The file is read by this:

```
IWorkbook iw = WorkbookFactory.Create(new FileStream(excelFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
ISheet sheet = iw.GetSheet(sheetName);
for (int j = rowStart; j <= sheet.LastRowNum; j++)
{
    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(j);
    if (row != null)
    {
        for (int i = row.FirstCellNum; i < row.LastCellNum; i++)
        {
            ICell cell = row.GetCell(i);
...
```

But the cell object has a lot of errors:
[image]

Do I have to include some references? Currently I've included:

```
using NPOI.HSSF.Model;
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.Util;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.Model;
using NPOI.XSSF.Util;
```

Comment: Is it failing immediately or at the end of the loop? Could it have anything to do with running from 1 to string.Length instead of 0 to string.Length - 1?

Comment: Initially was starting from 0, but getting the same error.

Comment: But where were you ending? For example, have you run (index = 0; index * **<** * richText.String.Length; index++)

Comment: It crashes at first iteration.

Comment: OK. Perhaps add that detail to the question just as a clarification.

Comment: What version of NPOI are you using? I've tried to reproduce your problem but failed to reproduce - I'm not getting null reference. My NPOI was built from sources taken from NPOI github repository at June, 2014. If your version is older - try to check latest one, it may be some bug fixed already.

Comment: Have same problem with DotNetCore.NPOI Version 1.2.3. It throws NRE at index 24 when Length of rtf is 38.